# Laptop reboots directly after bios

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have an HP EliteBook that refuses to boot the internal ssd.

The pc booted fine but went into a hang during the day and I had to force power off.

Since then it return to the first bios screen immediately after choosing the ssd as boot device.

Booting from usb works.

Booting from dvd drive works.

Gparted refuses to resize the partition, insisting I do a chkdsk.

Booting to Windows recovery disk I can see two partitions: a small at about 100 mb and a larger one which fills the rest of the disk. Both are readable.

I've since done the /fixmbr as well as bootrec /RebuildBcd but I'm still missing something.

As hinted to above the reboot seems to be happening right after choosing boot device before I see any sign of Windows.

Any ideas?

Edit: tried to do a system restore but it fails. 
Edit2: gave up, the PC is now happily running Elementary OS with Windows 10 in a VM. Still hoping for a good answer that can shed some light into low level Windows boot troubleshoot and repair.

Comment: Unfourtanlty it sounds like your installation is corrupt beyond your ability to repair it.  This normally happens when the boot device starts to fail and critical system files are on those sectors that are failing.

Comment: @Ramhound: that'd be annoying, I rarely give up PCs but then again at som point it isn't worth it. I'll still let the question stand for a while in case anyone knows a way to troubleshoot further.

Comment: @ErikI Have you actually run a chkdsk on that ssd or booted from a bootable CD/USB stick containing tools for troubleshooting disk errors?
Usually, the manufacturers of SSDs/HDDs have custom bootable tools for this as well. Reading the S.M.A.R.T. values with such a tool may also be a step forward.

Comment: @10100111001 Yes, I have run chkdsk. Haven't tried Intel troubleshooting disk though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to enter the F8 list before the windows restart ? If so you can use the "Last known good configuration" option to try a clean startup.

If not, I suggest to download a Hiren BootCD from here: http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd and to burn it to a blank CD.

It contains many tools that can help you explore the ssd and try to recover files if you need. I recommend to use the "mini windows XP" tool, it will give you a GUI way to recover files.

Maybe after that, you may try to format the ssd and reinstall Windows.

If you don't want to use Hiren tools, you may use a Lunix CD which offers the possibility to run without the need of an installation.

Let me know if you need help with a specific situation.

Comment: No, I see what you mean but it rebooted immediately after choosing ssd as boot device. I also tried going back to a snapshot using a Windows recovery DVD but that filed, as IIRC because writing failed.

Comment: Accepting this answer because that bootcd seems really useful (but will consider accepting another if I see a good explanation on low level windows boot troubleshoot and repair).